# Why matplotlib.pyplot.imsave() and matplotlib.pyplot.imshow() image qualities are different? How to ensure the same quality?

Tags: python, matplotlib

It seems `matplotlib.imsave()` lightens the image when compared to that of `matplotlib.imshow()`. For example, look at the code below.

```
import imageio
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

image = imageio.imread('image.jpg')
plt.imshow(image)
plt.imsave('image_new.jpg', image)

image_new = imageio.imread('image_new.jpg')
plt.imshow(image_new)
```

Saved image `image_new.jpg` (right) is slightly lighter than `image.jpg` (left).

[image: image.jpg]
[image: image_new.jpg]

image_source: https://c1.staticflickr.com/9/8191/8424182610_e23dcc6b4d_b.jpg

Comment: How exactly did you get this picture? Did you open both parts in the same program? Was it `plt.imshow` or an external image viewer?

Comment: it is very unlikely that a JPEG file loaded and re-saved as JPEG will have the same exact filesize. Among other things the quality settings (which tells the JPEG encoder how much of your image data to throw away) may be different. Even with the same quality setting, the image being saved is different in both cases (one being saved from a source image, the second from the first generation compression) so naturally they won't result in the same size of file. Generally, avoid creating multiple generations of JPEG files, as eventually you will end up with poor image quality and obvious artifacts.

Comment: @kindall: the same happens with lossless 'png' files too

Comment: @DYZ: it is plt.imshow('image.jpg') and plt.imshow('image_new.jpg') for left and right respectively.

Comment: So, your question is actually not about `imshow`. It is about why `imsave` distorts the image file. And as it turns out, even `imread/imwrite` distort the image file, even if it is a lossless PNG.

Comment: @DYZ: ya you are right. The question was about why  imsave distorts and is there a way to mitigate it.

Comment: You may want to rewrite your question and especially the title. It is unlikely that the future potential readers will be patient enough to go over this whole discussion.

Comment: Do you have any evidence that one of the images is lighter/darker? Or is this just a "feeling"? The right image is plotted with matplotlib, but that is not shown in the code, so one cannot verify.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest actually right image was shown with matpotlib only. Made the edits in the code here to reflect that.

Comment: Again, is there any evidence for one of them being lighter? [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VdsPO.png) is a histogram of the three channels. They are the same, except for a small artifacts due to compression. But those do not affect lightness.

Answer (score 0):

I am really ok with your result. so I try it with  CV2 and matplotlib:

```
import imageio
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import cv2; import os 
p0 = os.getcwd()
image1 = plt.imread(p0+'\\2.jpg') 
image = plt.imread(p0+'\\2.jpg')[:,:,0]

plt.subplot(141);plt.imshow(image1 );plt.title('Original image')
plt.imsave('image_plt.jpg',image )
imageio.imsave('image_imageio.jpg', image) 
imagecv2 =  image
cv2.imwrite('image_cv2.jpg',imagecv2 )

image_new = plt.imread('image_plt.jpg')[:,:,0]
plt.subplot(2,4,2);plt.title('read after save plt')
plt.imshow(image_new,cmap ='gray')

plt.subplot(2,4,6);plt.title('Diff original image with saved plt')
x=np.abs ( image - image_new)
plt.imshow(x,cmap ='gray')

image_cv2 = plt.imread('image_cv2.jpg')[:,: ]
plt.subplot(2,4,3);plt.title('read after save plt')
plt.imshow(image_new,cmap ='gray')
plt.subplot(2,4,7);plt.title('Diff original image with saved CV2')
x=np.abs ( image - image_cv2)
plt.imshow(x,cmap ='gray')

image_imageio = plt.imread('image_imageio.jpg')
plt.subplot(2,4,4);plt.title('read after save imageio')
plt.imshow(image_new,cmap ='gray')
plt.subplot(2,4,8);plt.title('Diff original image with saved imageio')
x=np.abs ( image - image_imageio)
plt.imshow(x,cmap ='gray')

figManager = plt.get_current_fig_manager()
figManager.window.showMaximized()
plt.savefig('diff.jpg')
```

Results:

[image]